# How to completely uninstall remove WebStorm IDE in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, uninstall, ide

How can I completely uninstall/remove JetBrains WebStorm IDE in Ubuntu? I already ran `rm -rf ~/WebStorm-145.1616.9/` to remove the installation folder and `rm -rf ~/.WebStorm2016.1/` to remove the config folder, but its not completely removed because the WebStorm icon still appears when I search for it in the Unity search bar.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, all answers are for many years ago, for versions around the year 2020 you should go to the `~` and find `.config` and `.cache` folder and then delete your specific folder version inside `JetBrains` folder:

```
~/.config/JetBrains/<product><version>
~/.cache/JetBrains/<product><version>
```

Answer (score 3):

Best way for doing is following the instructions in the Jetbrains website:
This is the link [jetbrains help center](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/uninstall.html)

Delete the installation directory.
in my case it is:

```bsh
sudo rm -rf /opt/WebStorm2021.2
```

Remove the following directories:

```bsh
sudo rm -rf ~/.config/JetBrains/WebStorm2021.2

sudo rm -rf ~/.cache/JetBrains/WebStorm2021.2

sudo rm -rf ~/.local/share/JetBrains/WebStorm2021.2
```

following these steps will clean remove the WebStorm completely from you machine :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1085997)

Comment: @music2myear hey thanks for mentioning that, I''m gonna do that

Answer (score 0):

you also need to remove the installation folder

like

```
/home/dev/Downloads/WebStorm-172.4343.25/
```

If you already removed the hidden files from your home directory just do it!